# IdHTTP.Get not waiting for answer

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, indy, idhttp

I'm having some problems with the Idhttp.Get method. I thought it's by default working in blocking-mode(wait for the answer to go to next line), but I just saw it's not waiting for the answer to go to another line. I'm using it with threads, but I think that's not the problem. The code is:

```
  IdHTTP1:= TIdHttp.Create(Application);
  IdHTTP1.ConnectTimeout:= 10000;
  IdHTTP1.Request.Clear;
  IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication:= true;
  IdHTTP1.Request.Username := Username;
  IdHTTP1.Request.Password := Password;
    try
      IdHTTP1.Get(PbxURL); **//this should STOP here and wait for answer don't?**
      HttpCode:= IdHTTP1.ResponseCode;
    except
      on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
        HttpCode := IdHTTP1.ResponseCode;
    end;
    if HttpCode=200 then
      Memo1.Lines.Append('Valid Get!');
```

So, I just notice that i'm not getting the right HttpCode value because after the 'Get' method, it just continue the execution without waiting for the 'Get' complete. How can I solve this problem??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say you're not getting the right HttpCode, which suggests you *are* getting an HttpCode, and that means the Get method has waited as long as it needed to to get a result.

If the response code you get is 301, then you should try setting the HandleRedirects property so it will automatically re-issue the request using the returned address. Otherwise, you'll have to handle the response yourself.

The Get function does not return prematurely. You're misinterpreting what you've observed.

Comment: I concur.  Indy exclusively uses blocking sockets and blocking operations, so it is not possible for your code to continue until `Get()` has exited first, whether normally or via a raised exception.

Comment: yes you are right. as I was working with threads, I created the IdHTTP in the wrong place, and it was working that way. Just changed the place where creating my IdHTTP object and it worked. Thank you.